# How can I use Twilio node with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, twilio

My code is:

```
import * as twilio from 'twilio';
import { IncomingCall } from '../models/IncomingCall';
const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
export function incoming(requestBody: any): any {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  return IncomingCall.create({
    CallSid: requestBody.CallSid,
    From: requestBody.From,
    To: requestBody.To,
    rawData: requestBody
  });
}
```

But I get an error when doing `new VoiceResponse()`:

```
[ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

I'm using Twilio v3.19.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [`@types/twilio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twilio) package which contains the type definitions for twilio.

Run `npm install @types/twilio` (or `yarn add @types/twilio` if you use yarn).

You can read more about the `@types/` packages [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/@types.html).

Comment: I tried that as well. No dice. I believe the twilio @types package is slightly out of date

Comment: Well then you could contribute to Definetly typed repo changes or define your own local types for Twilio library.

Comment: this package is of no use.

Comment: I just came across this and I wanted to point out that the Twilio package ships with its own types now and has done for a while :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use it with `new` because it's not a constructor.

Run `npm install twilio`
Then:

```
    import * as Twilio from 'twilio';


    const client = Twilio(accountSid, authToken);

    const message = await client.messages.create({
        body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
        from: twilioNumber,
        to: phoneNumber
    });
```

Twilio current version: "^3.49.0"

Comment: I dont use new and i get `TypeError: Twilio is not a function`. Package version is 3.75.1

Comment: when i add new I do see that it is a function ```(alias) function Twilio(accountSid?: string | undefined, authToken?: string | undefined, opts?: TwilioClient.TwilioClientOptions | undefined): TwilioClient
(alias) namespace Twilio
import Twilio
```

Comment: This is what worked for me as a workaround `import { default as twilio } from 'twilio';`

Answer (score 0):

This works more me:

```
import twilio from "twilio";

const client = twilio(
  "**",
  "***"
);
```